# How does this JavaScript syntax bit from Ember.js work?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, syntax, ecmascript-6

Going through the tutorial, I've encountered this:

```
this.render(hbs`
    {{#list-filter filter=(action 'filterByCity') as |results|}}
      <ul>
      {{#each results as |item|}}
        <li class="city">
          {{item.city}}
        </li>
      {{/each}}
      </ul>
    {{/list-filter}}
  `);
```

I thought backticks represented a string? What is `hbs` then? Is it a function that is receiving handlbars snippet as an argument?

Comment: hbs is handlebars. See the first answer in the dupe.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I figured. How come the backticks don't error out though, syntax-wise?

Comment: Coz, that's a valid syntax boss.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Since the question you linked and its answers don't address the template literal, it's not a duplicate. But it's strongly related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought backticks represented a string?

No, backticks represent a *template literal*, the result of which is usually a string, but isn't necessarily. You get a string when the template literal isn't *tagged*, but this is a *tagged* template literal, which is when a template literal is passed into a function (`hbs` in this case); the result is whatever the function returns. It doesn't look like a function call, but it is.

More on MDN: [Template lierals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

> What is `hbs` then?

`hbs` is a function providing handlebars handling for the template, see [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342583/node-js-hbs-module-and-engine).